# How to limit the number of items to be accepted by the droppable div(shopping cart) using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, shopping-cart, jquery-easyui

I am very new to jquery.I want to limit the number of items to be dragged in the droppable shopping cart.

eg:shopping cart should accept only three items on drop after that it should not accept any item.

jsfiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/

I have tried all other duplicates but din't work for me..
Any one out there please help me.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="keywords" content="jquery,ui,easy,easyui,web">
    <meta name="description" content="easyui help you build your web page easily!">
    <title>jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .products{
            list-style:none;
            margin-right:300px;
            padding:0px;
            height:100%;
        }
        .products li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }
        .item{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }
        .cart{
            position:fixed;
            right:0;
            top:0;
            width:300px;
            height:100%;
            background:#ccc;
            padding:0px 10px;
        }
        h1{
            text-align:center;
            color:#555;
        }
        h2{
            position:absolute;
            font-size:16px;
            left:10px;
            bottom:20px;
            color:#555;
        }
        .total{
            margin:0;
            text-align:right;
            padding-right:20px;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        var data = {"total":0,"rows":[]};
        var totalCost = 0;

        $(function(){
            $('#cartcontent').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true
            });
            $('.item').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });
            $('.cart').droppable({
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                }
            });
        });

        function addProduct(name,price){
            function add(){
                for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name){
                        row.quantity += 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name:name,
                    quantity:1,
                    price:price
                });
            }
            add();
            totalCost += price;
            $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
            $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;background:#fafafa;">
    <ul class="products">
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item">
                <img src="images/shirt1.gif"/>
                <div>
                    <p>Balloon</p>
                    <p>Price:$25</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item">
                <img src="images/shirt2.gif"/>
                <div>
                    <p>Feeling</p>
                    <p>Price:$25</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item">
                <img src="images/shirt3.gif"/>
                <div>
                    <p>Elephant</p>
                    <p>Price:$25</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item">
                <img src="images/shirt4.gif"/>
                <div>
                    <p>Stamps</p>
                    <p>Price:$25</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item">
                <img src="images/shirt5.gif"/>
                <div>
                    <p>Monogram</p>
                    <p>Price:$25</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#" class="item">
                <img src="images/shirt6.gif"/>
                <div>
                    <p>Rolling</p>
                    <p>Price:$25</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="cart">
        <h1>Shopping Cart</h1>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cartcontent" fitColumns="true" style="width:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <p class="total">Total: $0</p>
        <h2>Drop here to add to cart</h2>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here you go.. Modified your addProduct function to check for 3 items in `data.total`. if not give an alert..

try this

```
    function addProduct(name,price){
    if(data.total < 3){
       function add(){
         for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
            var row = data.rows[i];
            if (row.name == name){
                row.quantity += 1;
                return;
            }
         }
        data.total += 1;
        data.rows.push({
            name:name,
            quantity:1,
            price:price
        });
       }
        add();
        totalCost += price;
        $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
        $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
      }else{
        alert('cannot have more than 3 itrems');
      }
}
```

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Vwu37/8/)

**updated**

if you need to check for quantity then.. check for quantity instead of total.. :)

try this

```
 function addProduct(name,price){
    var totalQuantity=sumQuantity(data);

    if(totalQuantity < 3){
    function add(){
        for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
            var row = data.rows[i];
            if (row.name == name){
                row.quantity += 1;
                return;
            }
        }
        data.total += 1;
        data.rows.push({
            name:name,
            quantity:1,
            price:price
        });
    }
    add();
    totalCost += price;
    $('#cartcontent').datagrid('loadData', data);
    $('div.cart .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
    }else{
        alert('cannot have more than 3 itrems');
    }
}

//new function to sum up all the quantity.
function sumQuantity(data){
   var sum=0;
   for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
     sum += data.rows[i].quantity;
   }
   return sum;    
}
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bipen/Vwu37/9/)

Comment: That's exactly what i asked for but if we drop the same item three times or one of the items twice and the followed by another item this isn't working.Do you have a solution for this??